# Same authentication in 3 different web applications, that have their own database

Tags: java, mongodb

I have three REST web applications (Java) with their own database (MongoDB).

All the applications require authentication, so I created a collection called User in each database.

Now I want the same user to be able to log in each application.

Shall I have a fourth shared database only for user?

Shall I have a sort of synchronization process of the collection User among the three databases?

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to develop some microservice (OAuth2 for example) to do the authentication and implement all login and permission check routines by its means.

If that's an overkill for your task, it is better to make a separate DB for user accounts and synchronize application databases against it.